# Quando si usa "inglese" e quando si usa "l'inglese"?

Tags: grammar, articles

È da parecchio tempo che studio l'italiano, e una cosa che mi ha sempre confuso è la differenza tra l'uso di "inglese" in certi contesti, e l'uso di "l'inglese" in altri, quando non sembra di esserci nessuna distinzione nella sintassi della frase. Stavo cercando un esempio online per spiegare la mia confusione, e ho trovato [questo sito](https://englishlive.ef.com/it-it/lp/ts/impara-inglese-online-1/?ptn=goit&etag=GOIT_SG_OE_LEA_ENG_10PL_MB&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=it_it_sg_oe_gen_learn-english_cpc_zz&utm_content=lea_eng&utm_term=come%20imparare%20a%20parlare%20inglese&gclid=CjwKCAjw5s6WBhA4EiwACGncZbZy1I2Ss2oKVd2QJDgC9i_tUf10iMfh9hwSG6D1kY2_69mLhmTf8RoCvdIQAvD_BwE) che dice

> Impara l'inglese online...

E poi dopo dice

> Imparare a parlare inglese è in parte simile allo studio di altre materie...

La mia confusione è semplicemente che non capisco come mai si mette l'articolo nella prima frase, ma non nella seconda. Immagino che sia una domanda scema, con una risposta semplice che mi sono perso, ma vorrei avere le mie ansie calmate.

Grazie.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! A me sembra una domanda molto interessante!

Comment: La mia impressione è che in “parlare inglese” ci sia un complemento di modo e non un complemento oggetto.

Comment: Concordo pienamente, @egreg. Uno impara/studia/sa l'inglese/la matematica/le arti marziali, ma parla (in) inglese, con “inglese” usato in modo forse avverbiale. Quindi, OP, la sintassi delle due frasi è in realtà diversa.

Comment: Stellare. Grazie mille ragazzi. Per chiarezza: nella frase "parlare inglese", qual è l'elemento della frase che la rende un complemento di modo? Sarebbe l'uso implicito di "in", come ha notato @DaG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le due costruzioni “imparare l'inglese” e “parlare inglese” sono diverse dal punto di vista sintattico. Nella prima, [“inglese” è un nome](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inglese) che indica una certa lingua, e quindi fa da complemento oggetto di “imparare”, come in “imparare la matematica/le arti marziali/il modo per fare X”.

Nella seconda è un aggettivo usato in funzione avverbiale, analogamente a “piangere forte”, “lavorare sodo” o, in tempi più recenti, “votate socialista”.

Nella grammatica italiana di Serianni (XII.24) c'è proprio un esempio con “parlare italiano”:

> In qualche caso tra l'aggettivo avverbiale e l'avverbio corrispondente non vi è identità di significato: *parlare italiano* ‘parlare la lingua italiana’ / *parlare italianamente* ‘parlare da italiano, come si conviene a un italiano’

Answer (score 0):

Per me non c'è sostanziale differenza, eccettuata la sensazione (personale) che a volte uno possa suonare meglio dell'altro. I tuoi esempi rimangono corretti anche usando l'altra forma (aggiungendo l'articolo dove non c'è, togliendolo dove c'è).

Comment: Non sono del tutto d'accordo. Tu diresti davvero “Imparare inglese”?

Comment: No, però non mi suona impossibile.

Comment: Personalmente “Imparare inglese” mi suona monco, e anche “parlare l'inglese” mi suona poco idiomatico. Vedi anche le considerazioni di egreg e mie nei commenti alla domanda.

Answer (score -1):

*inglese* è sostantivo e aggettivo.

E' perciò corretto dire "imparo l'inglese", "odio l'inglese" e così via.

Come aggettivo, è corretto dire "il clima inglese", "la lingua inglese" eccetera.

La frase "parlare inglese" non è quindi formalmente corretta, ma si usa comunemente perché capita spesso di voler esprimere il concetto di "parlare l'inglese". Difatti, suona strano dire "imparo inglese", anche se suona meno strano dire "insegno inglese": dipende dal verbo che si usa, però è sempre corretto dire "imparo l'inglese" o "insegno l'inglese" usando il vocabolo per quello che è: un sostantivo.

Comment: Dovresti comunicare alle redazioni del Treccani (“Usare, nell’esprimersi, una determinata lingua: _al congresso parlavamo tutti l’inglese_ (o anche _inglese_, _in inglese_; e sempre con prep. _p. in lingua, in dialetto_); ... con aggettivi usati avverbialmente: _sentii che parlava straniero, forestiero_”, https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parlare2) e dello Zingarelli (“_parlare inglese, francese, tedesco; sa parlare cinque lingue; scusi, lei parla tedesco?; parla un italiano perfetto_”, paywall) che “parlare inglese” non è corretto.

Comment: E' per questo che ho usato la parola "formalmente", e ho accennato che dipende dal verbo che si usa. Dal mio punto di vista "parlare inglese" è come "mangiare sano" e "bere responsabile": molto usati ma, per la mia grammatica antiquata, scorretti.

Comment: Non capisco bene che cosa intendi: essendo un uso attestato fin dai primi autori italiani (è presente già in Dante e Boccaccio) e registrato nelle grammatiche e nei vocabolari, in che senso potremmo dire che sia “scorretto”?

Comment: Secondo il mio giudizio, visto che l'OP chiede quando si usa *inglese* e quando si usa *l'inglese*, rispondo che, nell'uso della parola come sostantivo, è sempre giusto usare l'articolo. Se non si usa l'articolo, ci sono locuzioni attestate, come dici tu, ma altre non attestate, come "imparo inglese" o "amo inglese". L'OP riporta la frase "Imparo l'inglese online", non si riferisce solo al verbo *parlare*.

Comment: È vero, questa è una giusta distinzione.